# How to programmatically click on Feature or particular region without coordinates?

Tags: arcgis-server, arcgis-maps-sdk-javascript

How  I can programmatically click on feature using javascript library, lets say in world countries map how can I programmatically click on a particular country ( i don't want to use co-ordinate as my does not deal with them).

Country Name comes form rest services. I will highlight the country through querytask i pass countryname in the country i get the feature object then i add symbol object to it and highlight it.

```
var queryTask = new esri.tasks.QueryTask("http://10.32.9.106:6080/arcgis/rest/services/KX_Mapping/World_countries_less_Antartica/MapServer/0");
var query = new esri.tasks.Query();
query.where="CNTRY_NAME IN ('Some')";
    queryTask.execute(query);
dojo.connect(queryTask, "onComplete", function(featureSet) {
                 try{
                        console.log(" query complete");
                        var symbol0 = new esri.symbol.SimpleFillSymbol().setColor(new dojo.Color([255, 0, 0, 0.9]));
                        dojo.forEach(featureSet.features,function(feature){
                                //alert('feature'+feature);
                                var graphic = feature;
                                graphic.setSymbol(symbol0);
                                //alert("infoTemplate"+infoTemplate);
                                var infoTemplate = new esri.InfoTemplate("Alert", "ds");
                                graphic.setInfoTemplate(infoTemplate);
                                //alert("graphic"+graphic);
                                //alert("map.graphics"+map.graphics);
                                map.graphics.add(graphic);
                        });
                    }catch(e){
                        alert("e"+e);
                    }
                });
```

I have associated infotemplate object to graphic object , template will be shown when user click on that country , how can i programitically  make it clickable.

Comment: What do you mean by 'programatticaly click'? What are you trying to achieve?

Comment: IN usual scenario uses takes mouses and say clicks on any country but lets say there is link of some country name out of map and when user clicks on country name i have to highlight that country , i.e i have to invoke onclick function of feature layer programitically that too at specific point

Comment: where is the country name? inside the map or somewhere else? And how will you highlight the country? Do you have the boundaries as a featurelayer? What have you tried so far? You need to provide more information to us.

Comment: Country Name comes form  rest services. I will highlight the country through querytask i pass countryname in the country i get the feature object i add symbol object to it and highlight it.

Comment: I tried to call click function to feature(graphic) object returned through query but it fails

Comment: You need to provide more information in a understandable manner. Unless you take efforts to communicate your issue, and tell us all that you have done, along with where you are stuck, and what all you have tried, we won't be able to help you out. We can't help you out. We can't read your mind. unless you ask a detailed question you won't get good questions.

Comment: I have edited the question to make it more clear

Comment: I think there is a key word missing from "as my does not deal with them".

Answer (score 2):

If you're trying to do something with a particular feature in a layer when the user clicks another layer or something outside the map, there isn't a click function for a feature. Instead, using some value from the user's interaction (say, the country name). Check the [selectFeatures](http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/featurelayer-amd.html#selectfeatures) function in the API documentation for FeatureLayer.

Comment: Thanks i am be select feature but To show infotemplate associated with it

Comment: @Anil - The info window belongs to the map, not to the feature. There's a sample for using the info window with a feature layer in the documentation at http://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jssamples/fl_popup.html.

Comment: problem it takes evt.mapPoint which comes from mouse click but i am doing it programitically

Comment: Is the country guaranteed to be showing in the map window? If so, you can find the centroid of the graphic (see https://developers.arcgis.com/en/javascript/jsapi/geometryservice-amd.html#labelpoints) and replace evt.mapPoint with the centroid.